# Jackson Annotation Issue

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

Json file

```
[
  {
    "1.symbol": "AAPL",
    "1.quantity": 100,
    "1.purchaseDate": "2019-01-02"
  },
  {
    "1.symbol": "MSFT",
    "1.quantity": 10,
    "1.purchaseDate": "2019-01-02"
  }
]
```

Now i want to parse this file to the java object.

My Class

```
// @JsonProperty("1. symbol")
  public String symbol;

// @JsonProperty("2. quantity")
  public int quantity;
  // public String quantity;

// @JsonProperty("3. purchaseDate")
  public String purchaseDate;
```

When using Json Property Getting this error

[image: When using Json Property Getting this error]

Comment: Your `JsonProperty` values don't match what's in your JSON (in multiple ways).

Comment: didnt understand, can you please elaborate, Thanks

Comment: @JsonProperty("1. symbol"), "1.symbol": "AAPL", remove the space in the annotation